# What is my mistake on this connection to my firebird database?

Tags: laravel, dependencies, firebird, firebird2.5

When I try to run composer requires harrygulliford/laravel-firebird i get the error:

> Root composer.json requires harrygulliford/laravel-firebird ^3.1 ->
> satisfiable by harrygulliford/laravel-firebird[v3.1.0].
> - harrygulliford/laravel-firebird v3.1.0 requires illuminate/support ^8.65|^9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.65.0,
> ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded,
> likely because it conflicts with another require.

I've changed my composer.json so many times. now I don't even know what could be wrong.

This is my composer.json file:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "illuminate/support": "^8.65|^9.0|^10.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I am trying to connect Laravel 9 to a Firebird 2.5 database if that context provides any help.

I tried changing the requirements, changing the versions of Laravel, of the herrygilford, starting a new project and installing the dependency also didn't work, and I am at a loss of where to go.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your application is using laravel 10. If you check your composer.json file, you can find

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.0.0",
```

The `harrygulliford/laravel-firebird` library does not support laravel 10 yet, so your fastest option would be to downgrade to laravel 9 or find another package with similar functionality ( or even make one yourself if you have the time and are willing to take the effort. Just fork the existing repo and make modifications and run tests ) .

To downgrade, change the line shown above in your composer.json to

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.0.0",
```

and run composer update.